# How can we initialize a python array without copying values from a different container?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

The following code snippet shows how to initialize a python array from various container classes (tuple, list, dictionary, set, etc...)

```
import array as arr
ar_iterator = arr.array('h', range(100))
ar_tuple    = arr.array('h', (0, 1, 2,))
ar_list     = arr.array('h', [0, 1, 2,])
ar_list     = arr.array('h', {0:None, 1:None, 2:None}.keys())
ar_set      = arr.array('h', set(range(100)))
ar_fset     = arr.array('h', frozenset(range(100)))
```

The array initialized from `range(100)` is particularly nice because an iterator does not need to store a hundred elements. It can simply store the current value and a transition function describing how to calculate the next value from the current value (add one to the current value every-time `__next__` is called).

However, what if the initial values of an array do not follow a simple pattern, such as counting upwards 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 99? An iterator might not be practical. It makes no sense to create a list, copy the list to the array, and then delete the list. You have essentially created the array twice and copied it unnecessarily. Is there someway to construct an array directly, by passing in the initial values?

Comment: If you're this worried about extra copies, Python may not be the language for you. Even if it were possible to do something like `array.array('h', 5, 2, 3, 14)` to create an array with initial contents `5, 2, 3, 14`, the arguments to `array.array` would be packed into a tuple as part of the function call mechanism, and you would be performing an "unnecessary" copy from a tuple to the array.

Answer (score 1):

From the python docs (https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html):

> class array.array(typecode[, initializer])
>
> A new array whose items are restricted by typecode, and initialized from the optional initializer value, **which must be a list, a bytes-like object, or iterable over elements of the appropriate type**.

So it would appear that you are constrained to passing in an initial python container.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the initial elements can be derived logically, you could pass a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators) as the initialiser.  Generators yield their elements as they are iterated over, similar to `range`.

```
>>> def g():
...     for _ in range(10):
...         yield random.randint(0, 100)
... 
>>> arr = array.array('h', g())
>>> arr
array('h', [47, 6, 91, 0, 76, 20, 77, 75, 46, 7])
```

For simple cases, a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) can be used:

```
>>> arr = array.array('h', (random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(10)))
>>> arr
array('h', [72, 30, 40, 58, 77, 74, 25, 6, 71, 58])
```